# Why blocking IO API was not a problem in Java in early days?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, nio

Original Java IO API is **synchronous**. Since 1.4 Java has NIO API which is **asynchronous**. How did it happens that system that was designed to be used in high-load systems did not care about performance and resource usage efficiency?

Technically it means that blocked thread consumes memory (~1-2Mb) and does not do anything useful. Also i do understand why it's considered to be ineffective: just because the work is actually done not by CPU but rather by network card or disk and they don't have threads. So there is not reason to block the thread actually theoretically. However most Java socket reading samples use reading thread blocked and waiting for incoming chars.

So i'd like to have **technical** explanation of why it was not a problem in early Java.

PS. The actual question for me comes into "what network and disk API to use: synchronous or asynchronous?". As Java developer i haven't care about it too much, but now we have C++ devs in the team and they consider synchronous Java IO as "serious Java issue".

PPS. I really like Kotlin coroutines concept as solution for this problem.

Comment: *How did it happens that system that was designed to be used in high-load systems did not care about performance and resource usage efficiency?* Java / Oak was originally designed for **set-top** boxes (low-load systems with high efficiency).

Comment: Blocking IO works fine with performance and efficiency.  There are some specific cases where non-blocking IO works better, but those are fairly specific.  In general blocking IO works fine for most problems.

Comment: i've mentioned why i consider as "non-efficient" - because thread overhead is allocated and not used when a thread is blocked

Comment: Have you built such a system?  Did you measure its performance?  Until you have some data in hand showing that "thread overhead" is the bottleneck I think your C++ programmers are making stuff up.

Comment: Yes, i've been working in high-load j2ee for 2 years. The performance optimizations was not a part of my job at that times. Let's not go into personal discussions. I think i've answered why i understand C++ devs consider it as inefficient.

Comment: Let's talk about a "serious C++ issue"; e.g. *C++ pro-tip: `#define private public`*

Comment: @Elliott That's out of scope of my question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've actually seen someone do that.  Real production code had a *#define* that redefined another set of global control *#define* for import statements.  I have no idea how that person was still working there.  *#define* is the devil's own tool.

Comment: @markspace If not having async IO API at all that kind of optimization is just impossible. So it's not a question of "premature optimization" but that kind of optimization available on platform in general.

Comment: I still don't believe that threads or blocking IO is a problem in most applications.  People who point to thread overhead in an IO bound environment don't understand either imo.  I'd need to see specific data to even start to believe that it's a real problem.

Comment: Imagine you have 10^3 of disk read/writing (or socket reading) threads that are mostly blocked. How much memory is allocated but not actually used?

Comment: @4ntoine In case of disk read/writing it depends. If you have enough ram you probably not get much of major-faults

Comment: "enough ram" means lot's of money thrown into smth that is used inefficiently and it's an indication of some possible problem

Comment: Why does someone in "the early days" has "10^3 of disk read/writing (or socket reading) threads" running at the same time?

Comment: It's just an example of high-load server (may be even not that high) which demonstrates use case. Do you think it's too imaginary use case?

Answer (score 1):

JVM's implementation of non-blocking IO depends greatly on the OS support for it, which, in Java's early days, was spotty and non-uniform. It was never "not a problem."

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However lack of technical possibility for such kind of optimization is still confusing. Still interested into getting technical explanation for the motivation.